# 2FA Android app

Tags: gratis, android

I search a two factor authentication OTP app for Android that fullfills these demands:

- gratis
- Google authenticator compatible
- TOTP at least
- protection by PIN or similar
- export function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you **[andOTP](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.shadowice.flocke.andotp/)** – which is gratis ***and free,*** support TOTP, is compatible with Google authenticator, offers protection by pin, password and even fingerprint – and also comes with an export function (in form of plain-text or encrypted backups); and thus meets all your requirements.

See [here](https://github.com/andOTP/andOTP#screenshots) for some screenshots – and if you insist, you can also find the app [on Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.shadowice.flocke.andotp).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I compared it to FreeOTP (my previous choice) and OpenOTP and it is the clear winner. A nifty detail: andOTP allows you to configure icons and *all* of my IAAS providers were available (digitalocean, scaleway, ovh, vultr, ...)

Comment: Indeed it does, used that already. Glad you like it as well! Another nifty detail is that the dev is quite active. I had an issue in the beginning, and got immediate response. Only have a few 2FA places, but I like the app – would chose it again anytime.